# Correct statistical analysis to use in R to determine significance of a ratio in two groups?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, biostatistics

I made some example data and an example graph to show what I need to do.

EDIT: Here is my original (example) data, and how the ratios I want to compare were obtained.

```
example.orig.labels <_ c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
example.orig.status <- c("+","+","+","+","+","+","+","-","-","-
","+","+","+","+","+","+","-","-","-","-")
example.df.orig <- data.frame(example.orig.labels,example.orig.status)
```

That created the original example data frame. I then filtered it and calculated percentages of %+ for each label A and B, as such...

```
example.a <- dplyr::filter(example.df.orig,example.orig.labels=="A")
example.b <- dplyr::filter(example.df.orig,example.orig.labels=="A")

ex.A.percent <- sum(example.a$example.orig.status=="+")/length(example.a$example.orig.labels)
ex.B.percent <- sum(example.b$example.orig.status=="+")/length(example.b$example.orig.labels)



example.label <- c("A","B")
example.percent.good <- c(ex.A.percent,ex.B.percent)
example.data <- data.frame(example.label,example.percent.good)
example.data$example.percent.bad <- (1-example.data$example.percent.good)

example.data ##looks like this
     example.label example.percent.good example.percent.bad
    1             A                 0.70                0.30
    2             B                 0.60                0.40
```

I then melted the data to be able to graph it using the reshape package.

```
example.melt <- melt(example.data,id.vars="example.label")

example.melt$labelposition <-
 ifelse(example.melt$variable=="example.percent.bad", example.melt$value/2, 1 - example.melt$value/2)
 ##This just creates where the graph should place the labels
```

The data then looks like this....

```
 example.label             variable value labelposition
1             A example.percent.good   0.7          0.65
2             B example.percent.good   0.6          0.70
3             A  example.percent.bad   0.3          0.15
4             B  example.percent.bad   0.4          0.20
```

I then graphed it using ggplot2. The graph looks like this.

[image: Graph]

What I then need to be able to do is to determine the statistical significance of the difference between those ratios. Obviously, in my actual data, the ratios came from somewhere, but here it is simply percentages in order to streamline the question, so there will be no significance within this particular example.

What is the correct statistical analysis to use to determine whether the difference between these ratios is statistically significant, and how do I accomplish this in R? Basically, is the 75%/25% in label A vs. the 60%/40% in label B statistically significant?

I have data and row information for this, however, I just went straight to percentages to streamline the question. Basically, the percentages are found by taking the number of values in a column with label "+" and dividing that by the length of the column to find "example.percent.good". The ratios are just ratios of + : - within a group labeled by A or B.

Comment: Your stripped-down, abstract question is unanswerable because it does not supply enough information to determine significance. Ratios usually don't come by themselves: they are derived from other data.  What are your *original* data in this case?  Counts?  Measurements of non-negative quantities?  Something else?  The proper way to understand and analyze them usually will be to analyze those original data rather than just the ratios.

Comment: @whuber I apologize for that. I tried to explain it briefly at the end, but I suppose to no avail. I will edit the question and show how the ratios were obtained.

Comment: Sorry, I skipped over the last paragraph.  You want to investigate information about *contingency tables* and *chi-squared tests,* both of which are amply represented on this site. You can also look up "test of proportions." Other closely related approaches are "loglinear models" and "logistic regression"--but they are likely overkill in this simple situation.  There are other approaches as well, of which one of the simplest and most intuitive would be a *permutation test.* For an introduction to the potential subtleties, look up "Fisher's Exact Test."

Comment: @whuber Much appreciated. I edited the question anyway, as it makes it more clear as to how the ratios were obtained.